# angular-bootstrap-slider get value as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Using [angular-bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/angular-bootstrap-slider) based on [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider).

I'm trying to get the value of a color by name (string), based my work on previous questions such as [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306539/custom-angularjs-bootstrap-slider) where there is a nice example of the options available.

Let's say I have two color options, Red & Blue, the user picks one, I want to save it as 'blue'.

I created a [working example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KhfPI2Df0MbQWfGjTJwP), and added the code below

All I manage to get is the tick value if I use a number object.

Script:

```
$scope.colorTypes = [0,1];

$scope.colorLabels = ['Red','Blue'];

$scope.colorTypeSlider = {
    ticks: $scope.colorTypes,
    ticks_labels: $scope.colorLabels,
    ticks_snap_bounds: 50
};
$scope.colorTypeVal = '';
```

HTML:

```
 <slider ng-model="colorTypeVal" ticks="colorTypeSlider.ticks"
                        ticks-labels="colorTypeSlider.ticks_labels"
                        ticks-snap-bounds="colorTypeSlider.ticks_snap_bounds"></slider>
                <h6> value check is: {{colorTypeVal}} </h6>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what you were looking for working in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wr9TkNFRqsRZufxNhDnW?p=preview), but there's definitely some weird behavior with the slider. I could only get it working by using the `onStartSlide` attribute within the directive to trigger a callback to select the color.

```
<slider ng-model="colors" 
        ticks="colorTypeSlider.ticks"
        ticks-labels="colorTypeSlider.ticks_labels"
        ticks-snap-bounds="colorTypeSlider.ticks_snap_bounds" 
        on-start-slide="selectColor($event,value,colorTypeSlider.ticks_labels)"></slider>
```

And I couldn't pass the `$scope.colors` array (of objects) to the function for some reason, it only worked with a an array of strings. Anyway, here's the function I used:

```
$scope.selectColor = function ($event,value,collection) {
  console.log('value is ' + value);
  $scope.selectedColor = collection[value];
};
```

And I passed in the `$scope.colorTypeSlider.ticks_labels` as the collection.

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks for that @BennetAdams, I appreciate the time and effort.

Comment: Need to solve the issue of now working only when sliding (onSlide), since clicking which is more natural gesture of the user, and now does not catch, tried to use 'change' but didn't call it correctly .

Comment: I think you can use the `on-start-slide` event attribute for the callback. I'll edit the plunker accordingly.